# Documentation of squared bracket `[` function

Tags: r, function, documentation, square-bracket, rd

I have a function in R that looks somewhat like this:

```
setMethod('[', signature(x="stack"),definition=function(x,i,j,drop){
  new('class', as(x, "SpatialPointsDataFrame")[i,]) })
```

I use it to get a single element out of a stacked object. For the package I'm building I need a .Rd file to document the function. I stored it as [.Rd but somehow the R CMD check does not see this. It returns:

```
Undocumented S4 methods:  generic '[' and siglist 'MoveStack,ANY,ANY'
```

The `[.Rd` file starts with these lines:

```
\name{[}    
\alias{[}
\alias{[,stack,ANY,ANY-method}    
\docType{methods}    
\title{Returns an object from a stack}    
\description{Returning a single object}    
\usage{
  \S4method{\[}{stack,ANY,ANY}(x,i,y,drop)
}
```

Any idea how I make R CMD check aware of this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the source code of the `sp` package, for example `SpatialPolygons-class.Rd`, the Methods section:

```
\section{Methods}{
Methods defined with class "SpatialPolygons" in the signature:
  \describe{
    \item{[}{\code{signature(obj = "SpatialPolygons")}: select subset of (sets of) polygons; NAs are not permitted in the row index}
    \item{plot}{\code{signature(x = "SpatialPolygons", y = "missing")}: 
    plot polygons in SpatialPolygons object}
    \item{summary}{\code{signature(object = "SpatialPolygons")}: summarize object}
    \item{rbind}{\code{signature(object = "SpatialPolygons")}: rbind-like method}
  }
}
```

method for `[` is defined.

Name and class of the file are

```
\name{SpatialPolygons-class}
\alias{[,SpatialPolygons-method}
```

If you look at the help page for `?SpatialPolygons` you should see

```
> Methods
> 
> Methods defined with class "SpatialPolygons" in the signature:
> 
> [ signature(obj = "SpatialPolygons"): select subset of (sets of)
> polygons; NAs are not permitted in the row index
>
```

So I would venture a guess that if you specify a proper (ASCII named) file name, give it an alias as in the above example, you should be fine.

Comment: Hi Roman, thanks for that hint. I changed the file name of the .Rd file to subset.Rd and changed the \name and \alias to \name{subset-method}

\alias{[,stack,ANY,ANY-method} . This solved the problem. Thanks!